# Word for emotional culmination, climax in work of art

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a word for highest point in a work of art, at which hero reconciles with, for instance, his long-time alienated relative, or forgives someone or in some other way gets a relief and release to his long-tormented negative emotions. This is like climax, but mostly climax with emotional relief.

Comment: No, it's not acme.

Comment: I've seen *cognitio* and *anagnorisis* describe this kind of thing, mainly in lit. crit. with a penchant for Latin and Greek.

Comment: One of Google's definitions of **"denouement"** (day-noo-ma) is "the climax of a chain of events, usually when something is decided or made clear."

Comment: Isn't it, er, 'climax'?

Comment: No, Dan, as commenters below has uninentionally mentioned it - the word I was looking for is catharsis, I was maybe a bit wrong with limiting it to the art, but generally that's where we meet this kind of thing most.

Comment: Did you look it up in a thesaurus?

Comment: Yep, I was looking in thesaurus and synonym dictionaries, looked through numberous synonyms for a dozen of words that I was able to think of before (and in proccess of) getting here. Not sure why there was no catharsis there. For instance, in one dictionary catharsis and "emotional release" are linked, but not the "release" that was among the words that I've checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word I was looking for is catharsis. It's definition is, according to [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/catharsis) is:

> The process of releasing, and thereby providing relief from, strong or repressed emotions:
>   *‘music is a means of catharsis for them’*

Generally that word mostly related to purification through art, but [not necessary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catharsis).

Answer (score 1):

The closest I could think of is **Dénouement** : See [Dramatic Structure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dramatic_structure).
According to Freytag's analysis:

> The dénouement comprises events from the end of the falling action to the actual ending scene of the drama or narrative. Conflicts are resolved, creating normality for the characters and a sense of catharsis, or release of tension and anxiety, for the reader. ***Etymologically, the French word dénouement is derived from the word dénouer, "to untie", from nodus, Latin for "knot". It is the unraveling or untying of the complexities of a plot.***
>
> The comedy ends with a dénouement (a conclusion), in which the protagonist is better off than at the story's outset. The tragedy ends with a catastrophe, in which the protagonist is worse off than at the beginning of the narrative. Exemplary of a comic dénouement is the final scene of Shakespeare’s comedy As You Like It, in which couples marry, an evildoer repents, two disguised characters are revealed for all to see, and a ruler is restored to power.

The [dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/denouement) defines the word as *the final part of the play* (not always a happy ending) but owing to the it's origin it does imply to 'emotional relief'.

Comment: I've always associated denouement with being cathartic for the reader, not necessarily for the protagonist. The protagonist could very well find that they were in fact dead all along!

Comment: And Tushar Raj is the one winning the prize: I was looking for the word "catharsis"! Thanks.

Comment: @TiGR Didn't 'catharsis' click in your head when you saw it in the 1st para of the answer? Or did you not read this excessively-long-cumbersome answer :)

Comment: Missed that absolutely. Marked your answer as solution. Thanks

Comment: @TiGR I didn't mean you to accept my answer. If you're not satisfied you can post your own answer and accept it, I guess.

Comment: @Nikki, okay, I've created my answer, and as the system tells me I'll be able to accept it in two days.